# MYSQL How to convert '2013-8-21' to date format

Tags: mysql, date

I want to convert `'2013-8-21'` to `'2013-08-21'` **(MYSQL date format)**
I have tried following:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2013-8-21","%Y%c%d");`

I am getting null instead of a valid result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format would be :
`SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2013-8-21","%Y-%c-%d");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DATE_FORMAT('1997-10-04', '%Y %m %d');
```

More information on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: You have 2013-8-21 in your database and you want select this date with this format? 2013-08-21? The problem is just the 0 before 8? If it's case replace %c by %m

Comment: no for zero padded month numeric we use %m, for non zero padded month we use %c. I have posted the correct answer.Thanks for help :)